# remove items from listview by pressing delete button android

Tags: android, listview

I want to  delete my listview items when I press delete button but the problem is I should first press listview row then press delete button to remove it. I want to delete items immediately after pressing delete button not first press on listview then press delete button
Can you help me in this situation?

and this is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.wholeshop);

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem

final View view = v;
final int pos =position;        
deleteone= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.bdeleteone);
    deleteone.getTag(position);
    deleteone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
            deleteone.setTag(view);
                productsList.remove(pos);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    wholeShop.this, productsList,
                    R.layout.listshop, new String[] { "name",
                          "spinn","price"},
                    new int[] { R.id.wholename, R.id.wholespinn,R.id.wholeprice });
            // updating listview

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });  
    }
});
```

}

and this is my xmlfile for listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="#ffffff">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
     </ListView>
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="#ffffff"
android:weightSum="100">




 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/wholename"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="left"
     android:layout_weight="40"
     android:paddingLeft="5dip"
     android:text="Flower Name"
     android:textColor="#000000" />




 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/wholespinn"
     android:layout_width="66dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dip"
     android:text="Flower spinn"
     android:textColor="#000000" 
      android:layout_weight="30"/>

<TextView

android:id="@+id/wholeprice"
 android:text="Flower price"
 android:layout_gravity="right"
 android:paddingRight="10dip"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:layout_weight="30"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bdeleteone"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Del" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:focusable="false"
   />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going with wrong way.

You may have to look this [Example.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/)

You have create Your Own Adapter like:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  
    customButtonListener customListner;  

    public interface customButtonListener {  
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);  
    }  

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {  
        this.customListner = listener;  
    }  

    private Context context;  
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();  

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataItem) {  
        super(context, R.layout.child_listview, dataItem);  
        this.data = dataItem;  
        this.context = context;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        ViewHolder viewHolder;  
        if (convertView == null) {  
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_listview, null);  
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();  
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView  
                    .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);  
            viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView  
                    .findViewById(R.id.childButton);  
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);  
        } else {  
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
        }  
        final String temp = getItem(position);  
        viewHolder.text.setText(temp);  
        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                if (customListner != null) {  
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position,temp);  
                }  

            }  
        });  

        return convertView;  
    }  

    public class ViewHolder {  
        TextView text;  
        Button button;  
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: No I think I am right to do this way :) #SOreadyToHelp @Blackbelt